# Dart SIMD extensions (Int32x4, Float32x4) going crazy: slow in AoT, different results on ARM and Intel

Tags: flutter, dart, optimization, cpu-architecture, simd

I've been playing with SIMD classes from [dart:typed_data](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.6/dart-typed_data/dart-typed_data-library.html), specifically Int32x4 and Float32x4. Tested my code on Apple Silicon Mac (M1 Pro) and Linux VM (Intel® Core™ i5-8257U CPU @ 1.40GHz).

Here's the [file](https://github.com/maxim-saplin/mandelbrot/blob/main/_optimized/mandelbrot.dart). You can run it:

1. Via Dart VM: `dart mandelbrot.dart`
2. by building (Ahead-of-Time compilation) and running the executable:

```
dart compile exe mandelbrot.dart 
./mandelbrot.exe
```

The point of interest is `Uint8List mandelbrot()` function. Same Dart code executed on 2 different CPU architectures in 2 different modes.

What shocked me:

1. AoT was **~40-50 times slower** than VM on both ARM and Intel machines:

> **ARM** VM - Avg: 93.4ms, StdDev: 1.6119%; AoT - Avg: 4038.5ms, StdDev: 0.6437%

> **Intel** VM - Avg: 162.9ms, StdDev: 7.5598%; AoT - Avg: 8806.0ms, StdDev: 4.4871%

... what kind of performance one might get when utilising SIMD with Flutter apps which are AoT in Release modes...

2. Huge **discrepancies in results**, by simply calculating the sum of the elements produced by the function (the right one is 78513425) we get discrepancies within 10% range. Few tenth of a percent would be fine, assuming floating point math and precision differences. 1% is already a lot, 10% is crazy:

> **ARM** VM sum 78513692; AoT sum 78513692

> **Intel** VM sum 87667671; AoT sum 78513692

Am I doing something wrong?

JIC, here's the function:

```dart
Uint8List mandelbrot() {
  var output = Uint8List(width * height);
  final escapeThreshold = Float32x4(4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0);

  for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
    double cy = min_y + h * scaley;
    Float32x4 cy4 = Float32x4.splat(cy);

    for (int w = 0; w < width; w += 4) {
      Float32x4 cxx4 = Float32x4(min_x + w * scalex, min_x + (w + 1) * scalex,
          min_x + (w + 2) * scalex, min_x + (w + 3) * scalex);
      Float32x4 zx = cxx4;
      Float32x4 zy = cy4;
      Int32x4 nv4 = Int32x4(0, 0, 0, 0);
      int mask = 1;
      var iter = 2;

      while (mask > 0) {
        Float32x4 zzx = zx * zx;
        Float32x4 zzy = zy * zy;

        Float32x4 new_zx = (zzx - zzy) + cxx4;
        zy = (zx * zy) + (zx * zy) + cy4;
        zx = new_zx;

        var sum = zzx + zzy;

        Int32x4 breakCondition = (escapeThreshold).greaterThan(sum);
        nv4 += breakCondition & Int32x4(1, 1, 1, 1);

        iter++;
        if (iter > MAX_ITERS) {
          break;
        }
        mask = breakCondition.signMask;
      }

      output[h * width + w] = nv4.x;
      output[h * width + w + 1] = nv4.y;
      output[h * width + w + 2] = nv4.z;
      output[h * width + w + 3] = nv4.w;
    }
  }

  return output;
}
```

Same Dart code is supposed to work OK no matter VM or AoT, ARM or Intel.

Environments:

- macOS 13.6, Dart SDK version: 3.1.2, MacBook Pro with M1 Pro CPU
- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, 64 bit, Dart SDK version: 3.1.0, Intel Core i5-8257U @ 1.4GHz x 2, VMWare Workstation Player 17.0.1

Comment: How does this end up getting compiled in the AoT case? I tried something [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Te86Gf5xd) but I couldn't get any optimization option to work (well I never use Dart, I don't know what I'm nothing). As I compiled it there, the result is horrible (with calls to library implementations of vector operations, no direct use of SIMD)

Comment: Who cares how it gets compiled) The build command completes without errors, the binary starts and finished just right. It happens that it super slow

Comment: Yes but look at the asm. That at least tells what is happening, though not *why* it happens. Do you get the same thing as I got on godbolt? The immediate reason for slowness is obvious there: SIMD didn't work, we get fallback to library functions. IDK why that would happen but that's at least a starting point.

Comment: That's a nice tool you just shared: https://godbolt.org/z/4exPbx5xY - here's a smaller version of my file. Apparently it is compiled with aot-snapshot param (An architecture-specific file containing the source code compiled to machine code, but no Dart runtime), while I compile with exe (A standalone, architecture-specific executable file containing the source code compiled to machine code and a small Dart runtime) - though I wouldn't expect there to be much of a difference. Btw, this code implemented without SIMD runs OK in JIT/VM and AoT modes

Comment: We care how it compiled because CPUs run machine code, not source, so the reason for slowness will be in the compiler-generated assembly.  e.g. in the Godbolt link from your last comment, with no compiler options, the code gen is a total disaster like @harold described: instead of one `addps` instruction, we get some scalar `push` instructions and  `call   a7d78 <_Float32x4.operator_add_1705>`. That looks like a debug build, though, where that's expected.

Comment: It's normal that manual vectorization with intrinsic functions ends up slower than scalar in an unoptimized debug build, because they compile to actual function calls with so much extra store/reload of the vector data.  So unless you can provide compiler options that get the compiler to make asm like what was actually running on your CPU in your test cases, we can't see why that might be slow.  Only that the compiler output we can see is total garbage.

Comment: dart compile exe mandelbrot.dart 
./mandelbrot.exe

Comment: https://dart.dev/tools/dart-compile

Comment: The only mention of optimization options I see in that link is for compiling to Javascript.  If Dart's compiler isn't capable of optimizing AoT builds, they're useless for performance, at least the way it compiles SIMD intrinsics.  That would be surprising, but again, I know nothing about Dart or its toolchain other than what I've seen in the few minutes I've spent looking at this question.

Comment: Although not mentioned specifically in the docs, judging by the results I've seen in Flutter release builds and command line apps built with Dart (Dart is the runtime of Flutter), Dart creates optimised binaries via compile

Comment: Oh, btw, I've been playing with Dart optimisations over the weekend, without any SIMD `dart compile exe` produced quite capable results: https://github.com/maxim-saplin/mandelbrot/tree/main/_optimized

Comment: Comparing the performance of a Dart code with one in C# is certainly not very useful since both may not be optimized. Even worse : the code is run in VMWare Workstation Player (i.e. VM). The VM may not even support SIMD instructions if not properly configured... Comparing the Dart code with one like C/C++/Rust on a bare metal machine would make much more sense. By the way, the code operates on 128-bit registers which are clearly sub-optimal (x2) on any recent mainstream x86-64 CPU.

Comment: SIMD is supported on the VM, C# and Dart are optimized, no need to speculate here